Can modern civilization maintain itself under an Earth constantly bombarded with lightning?
I have an Earth unknowingly tainted by a drop of blood shed from a Lightning Deity. The divine blood corrupted the world such that it is always experiencing lightning strikes at an omnipresent scale. On average, each 7 square meters will get struck by lightning 7 times with a 7 second interval between each strike. After each iteration, there's a cooldown of 77 seconds before the strikes happens again. The source of the lightning strikes comes from portals that appear and disappear quickly so this Earth isn't trapped under an eternal thunderstorm. Asides from its source and frequency, the lightning strikes aren't any different from real ones.
The Mystic Hivemind(a human hivemind), having finally located a lead for its search for Divinity, is overjoyed and wants to create a base on this Earth by incrementally introducing 7 billion of itself. Because of certain restraints, it can only develop up until modern human civilization under this Earth, specifically the associated technology and infrastructure. As a Hivemind, it holds all the needed knowledge, expertise, and coordination required for such an endeavor.
My question is: Can a modern civilization indefinitely sustain, maintain and adapt itself under this specific environment?

How do you account for the fact that all this lightning would probably result in the surface rocks melting?

Quite modern of the Lighting Deities to use multiples of SI units for their portal schedule!

can humans civilization is you incernerate everything on the surface of the earth non-stop, no, why even ask the question. humans can't survive without plant life.

No. Not even close. These lightning strikes each carry roughly 7GJ of energy, and they strike each square meter every 120s. The average power they supply the world is 8MJ/sqm, which is 33,000 times as much as the Sun. You think Mercury is hot? It's only receiving 10 times the insolation of Earth. In the first day after the drop of blood falls, this poor Earth receives enough energy to boil (not melt, fully vaporize) roughly 300 meters of rock across its entire surface, and this energy input does not slow down. Some napkin math suggests that the equilibrium temperature on this world is comfortably above red-hot and into the light yellows. It would quite literally be easier to live in the mantle with all the lava than it would on the surface of this world, even before we consider the fact that electrical anything is impossible to use here. The surface of this world is a dense soup of superhot plasma (vaporized rock) comparable to the inside of a blast furnace, but everywhere, constantly scintillating with lethal electric currents, blowing over the surface of an endless ocean of lava.

Maybe if we edit the question a little. Like some sort of energy equilibrium needs to be maintained, so the mysterious lightstrike power suck equivalent amount of various forms of energy from surrounding area before every strike. Results would still be very destructive, as energy is quickly shifted around and focused, but not on the "melt whole planet and atmosphere away" level

I'm skeptical about the ability of a human to survive having even a few KJ of heat magically ripped out of their body, but at least this way you could plausibly handwave people living deep beneath the earth where the cooling effect doesn't reach. (At the cost of including more inexplicable magic)

I think the answer is negative, but on a different reason. A lightning has about 1GJ energy, thus about 30l of burning petrol. Check on the youtube, how does a liter of burning petrol look.
77s cooldown won't be enough. We will be burned in minutes.
Maybe 7 square km, so it would be well survivable.

Agreed, the surface of the planet will cook in its own (ionised) juices.  The rate of input vastly exceeds the ability to radiate the energy back into space, even if there are 100% efficient lightning rods (which are well beyond modern technological capability).

To add onto this, the sun adds ~21MJ/(m2day) to the world (average incl. nights) and the average energy of a bolt is 7GJ. So if the world is dark and lit only by lightning, 0.003 bolts/(m2day) equals the energy input of the missing Sun - in the 15km around you that lightning is audible, this is 24 bolts per second, and lightning is visible from much  further than its's audible. Despite this being effectively a constant assault on the senses, and adding fully as much energy to the world as the Sun does, it's 240,000 times less than your scenario
